# Boss stole my project

Tags: management, leadership, bullying

I am an IT professional at a non-profit. I enjoy the work I do, and as a person I enjoy taking on interesting and fulfilling projects. Our office building has a small back yard area that has gone untouched for about a decade and was overgrown. I recently took the initiative to clean the backyard and make it usable, and a couple other people jumped on board to help.

Recently, since completing the initial hard work, the executive director has taken to making connections with outside people to work towards his vision of what he wants that area to be, and I have not been consulted or included in the planning. I am somewhat insulted by that behavior. I suspect that if I had not taken the initiative, no one would have done any work on it, and now he has claimed it as his own territory to be done with as he pleases.

Should I talk to him about it? If so, what can I say to be included in future developments?

Editor's Note: The original poster later modified the post to read "Disregard... Problem Solved...".  In the interest of helping others looking for help in similar situations a rollback to the prior version was done.

Comment: a boss being a boss is not bullying..

Comment: Explain "Being a boss"

Comment: How is that bullying?  You can talk to him but I would not use the word bully nor territory.

Comment: He left something untouched, waited for someone else to take initiative, then took it back when it looked interesting because "it's his" and he can do that because I am powerless to prevent it. It's like watching a spoiled child steal toys back because someone else wanted to play with them.

Comment: @NonSecwitter it's his company, his yard, etc.  He's free to do with it what he chooses.  You aren't.  Talk to him about the work you've done for him.  But it literally IS his territory.  Not yours.

Comment: I suppose in a legal sense that's right. It's definitely terrible leadership and it's going to work against him, because I now have zero motivation to take initiative outside the limited scope of my job description. What's the point if I can't get credit for my work?

Comment: Welcome @NonSecwitter! I hope that you find some useful advice here for your dilemma.

Comment: @NonSecwitter did you expect to get promoted to Information Gardening Officer or more of a pat on the back?  Perhaps it'd be best to talk to him about the effort you put into it and ask if you can continue to be involved.  Wouldn't hurt.  At least you motivated him to beautify the space!

Comment: @easymoden00b Was about to say the 2nd part of your comment.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand you are not happy that your initial action has had such a major effect on the organisation, from your direct colleagues to your boss. Obviously you require praise, but it simply is not up to you to decide whether you deserve any.

Comment: I don't get credit for it. When talking to outside people he actually avoids answering the common question of how the project got started. His purpose for getting involve is to get credit among the people he is trying to impress and to fit his naïve vision of a boys club hangout. I started the project as a way to give our overworked staff a place to relax and take reprieve from their work. His motivation is not about the organization, it's about his own vision.

Comment: Apparently I'm not conveying something well because my co-workers and the COO think that what the CEO is doing in hijacking the project is messed up, but I'm getting a bunch of down votes. What I hear is that because he has the legal right to do it, I have no reason to feel like he's done anything wrong. I'm disappointed by that.

Comment: What's your actual question? This reads more like a rant/complaint but without any actual question it's hard to really answer..

Comment: @NonSecwitter Other than the fact that you helped out with cleaning the yard, or perhaps proposed the idea to clean the yard, I don't see why that means that *you* get to decide what your boss uses that space for in the future. Basically it's a resource and someone has ownership of that resource. Helping out to improve it so it can be well-utilized is admirable. Complaining about how the resource is being used by its owner is not admirable.

Comment: He doesn't own the resource. It's a non-profit with a board. Why wouldn't I get to decide what happens with a resource that has been left to waste, if I am the one that makes use of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations on cleaning up the area.  Few people would do such a thing.  Where I work most people won't bother to clean up messes they leave in the shared microwave and refrigerator.

To start addressing your concerns: Are you certain the boss was not already planning to make a different use of the area? That he wasn't already in communication with these outside people who are going to help him achieve his vision for the area? It is possible there were plans already in place that you weren't aware of.

It seems there is a lack of communication here. While unfortunate, that seems common in IT. From what I see, any hope you have to resolve this issue in a way you find favorable will require that you improve your communications with your boss. That said, there's no guarantee that improved communications will get you what you want.

To start with, I suggest asking your boss if you can talk about the back yard. Say something like "Mary, Tom, and I worked a lot to clear that area up. We were hoping to use it as an area to get some sun while we take relaxation breaks. Now it seems you want to convert it to a glassed in office.  Is there any way we can re-visit that plan?" Of course, you will change the details to fit the facts of your situation. The boss may say something like:

- "Oh, I didn't realize and hadn't thought of using it that way, I like that idea."
- Or maybe "Hmm, I really need that glassed in office, as that potential client loves things like that. However, we can compromise by splitting the space and making some of both."
- Of course, you might get something like "Sorry, it's my space and I've made my own plans for it."

The first reaction should be to your liking. The second will require some work on both your parts; maybe neither of you will be completely happy, but you'll each get something toward what you want. In the third case you're unlucky; regardless, you'll have tried and let the boss know your feelings about the matter. In the future, improved communications are likely to avoid situations like you are in now.

Another thought: Did you do this clean up on your own time or was it something you did during work? If it's the latter, the boss may be upset with you for doing something outside the scope of your job. (Now, I must get back to work myself!)

Comment: He had no plans for the space, just passing comments about what he would like to do with it. I had communicated my intention to re-work the back yard, and he thought it was quite the joke. I do my best to communicate with people because my field does have so many problems with that.

I've gotten comments from other staff that this is par for course for him. Looking back, it's not the first time he has presented other ideas as his own. I've made suggestions for our fundraiser that were met with objection, only for him to come back to me later and present it as a new idea.

Comment: If you had discussed the project in advance and he indicated it was a joke that is a different slant.  And you feel he has taken other ideas as his own.  You should have included that in the question.

Answer (score 7):

You can certainly talk to him about it. He may very well be impressed by your initiative, though that does not mean he feels a need to consult you on further developments, nor does he have any obligation too. (Unless more has happened than you've disclosed, you are not being bullied.)

If you would like to be part of the project, you can certainly raise that with him. But the solution here is to raise it with him directly as with any other project: professionally, emphasizing your interest and initiative, and see if there's a way of getting involved now that it's becoming a formal, organisational project.